# Setting an array element with a sequence while fitting in sklearn naive bayes model

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

My pandas dataframe looks like:

```
0 [0,1,2]    [1,2,3]   [1,2,3]
1 [0,1]      [1,2]     [1,2]
2 [0,1,2,3] [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4]
```

When I try to fit this model with:

```
features=df.iloc[:,:2].values
output= df.iloc[:,2].values
gnb=GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(features,output)
```

I get the error as:

```
setting an array element with a sequence
```

After reading some answers I tried appending 0 and making all lists equal but the error remains the same.

The df after appending 0's

```
0 [0,1,2,0]    [1,2,3,0]   [1,2,3,0]
1 [0,1,0,0]    [1,2,3,0]   [1,2,0,0]
2 [0,1,2,3]    [1,2,3,4]   [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html) the `GaussianNB` `fit()` method takes in two arguments x,y where x should be of the shape `[n_samples, n_features]` which means a 2D array and y should be of the shape `[n_samples]` which is a 1D array.

When you do `features=df.iloc[:,:2].values` it returns a 3D array with datatype object, so you'll first have to convert them to integer and also find a way to convert them into a 2D array

In the `y` parameter also you'll have to convert them into `int` then into a 1D array because the GaussianNB will only return a single value per training sample.

The sample example in the docs is a good referrence.

Comment: when I print the dimension of featuers array it gives 2

Comment: Is the datatype of that array integer, first convert them into `int`, you cannot pass strings to a model?

Comment: I rechecked the datatype, it is `int`